# In Notepad++ how to find lines matching 2 ":"

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to search/find lines containing "@" then 2 times ":"

A few examples :

```
www@xxx:yyy:zzz would match (it contains "@" then ":" then ":" again)
sample:help:new would not match (no "@")
fun@blue:turtle would not match (only 1 time ":")
```

Many thanks!

Comment: @SilviuBurcea You can do regex searches in Notepad++ (in the bottom left of the `Find` window, there is a radio button titled "Regular expression"). I can't seem to see the version that it was added, but it's been in for the last few releases, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: @maxy Are you in Windows?

Comment: @MattChampion It's been there for years. The feature is already ancient.

Comment: @konsolebox Fair enough. Unfortunately I've only used Notepad++ for a short while and hadn't come across the regex feature until recently (mainly through lack of necessity), so I didn't want to commit myself to saying that it has been there a while unless I was sure. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the lines which has atleast one `@`,two `:` symbols then you could try the below regex.

```
^.*@.*:.*:.*$
```

If you want to print the lines which has exactly one `@` symbol and two or more `:` symbols then you could try the below.

```
^[^@]*@[^@]*:[^@]*:[^@]*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bT6wQ5/1)

Comment: You won't even need the non-greediness; even greedy quantifiers prioritize finding a match over matching the maximum number of characters. Try `^.*@.*:.*:.*$`.

Comment: did you want any number of `:` after @ ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj after @ only 2 or more ":". Thanks all.

Comment: i thought there would be an exact 2 : after @. you may try `^.*@.*:.*:.*$`

Comment: @maxy did you want only one `@` in that line?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors whenn you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

Also this will work:

```
.*?@.*?:.*?:.*
```

Answer (score 0):

In the given example ,

```
www@xxx:yyy:zzz would match 
sample:help:new would not match 
fun@blue:turtle would not match
```

To match `www@xxx:yyy:zzz would match` alone , use the following

**Answer:** `((@.*){1})((:.*){2})`

**Explanation:**

`((@.*){1}) --> To match single @`

`((:.*){2}) --> To match two :`

**Note:** Used Notepad++ **6.6.3** for testing the above regex